# Can't access an excel pivot table field through a string value in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I am trying to access a row field in an Excel Spreadsheet through a VBA Macro

```
Sub EnableSelectionSelPF()
'pivot table tutorial by contextures.com

'This is the Excel Module that will enable
'the selection for a single piviot table
'column on the first table of the sheet

Dim PT As PivotTable
Dim PF As PivotField
Dim Column As String

Column = "Service Address"

On Error Resume Next
Set PT = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
Set PF = PT.RowFields(Column)
    PF.EnableItemSelection = True
End Sub
```

When replacing the column string variable with a numerical index value I'm able to access the desired field, however trying to use the string variable, `Column`, or a string value as the Index yields no results for me.

I've checked to make sure that `PT.RowFields()` could take string values so I'm not quite sure what the problem is.

Base Code Acquired From: [Contextures](http://www.contextures.com/xlPivot12.html)

Comment: Could you remove `On Error Resume Next` and tell us what error you're getting?

Comment: And on what line is the error? And are you sure that the text based value is present in the rowfields? Index is position matching not name matching so will be fine so long as something is present at position 1.

Comment: Run-time error '1004':
Unable to get the RowFields property of the PivotTable class

on the `Set PF = PT.RowFields(Column)`

Comment: Did you try `Set PF = PT.PivotFields(Column)` ?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried PivotFields, DataFields, Row, Column, Page

Comment: @Qharr [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/pivottable-rowfields-property-excel) I'm almost certain that Name matching is allowed. However I could be misreading information. Also in the link provided above there is an example of using a string value to match a piviot table item

Comment: Name matching IS allowed but it is more specifc than index. Index will work so long as there is anything at that index. Name only if a matching Name is found. That was my point.

Comment: @Qharr My bad, I didn't understand. Still might not, What i have tried is making sure the variable and corresponding value are both spelled consistently. I've also tried other pivot fields and none of them have come back with results

Comment: Can you post a picture of the PivotTable with the part of it you want to select highlighted? Also suggest you check out https://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/

Comment: @Jeffreyweir Google Doc Explanation [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/17UVADl4Flx5cCqVnM0A_yRvrfITdGu-uIX7fXAdn5w8/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Run the following, and see what it returns: `Sub EnableSelectionSelPF()
Dim PT As PivotTable
Dim PF As PivotField

Set PT = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
Set PF = PT.RowFields(2)
MsgBox PF.Name
Debug.Print PF.Name
End Sub`

Comment: Also, what is it that you want your code to accomplish, and how do you know whether it is working or not?